# Calling Connection.setReadOnly() when using Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm building a tool that uses Spring JdbcTemplates to manage an arbitrary number of MySQL / MariaDB instances through mysql-connector-j library.  I need the ability to have any statements executed on a given datasource to be readOnly occasionally.  I would rather a way to call Connection.setReadOnly() through a Spring JdbcTemplate callback or something over using @Transactional annotation because every statement needs to be readOnly.  I know worst case I could create a wrapper DataSource class that could get the job done, but wanted to see how else others support such a need other than code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JdbcTemplate::execute(ConnectionCallback<T> action)` and then `setReadOnly` on the supplied connection.

Comment: Thanks Trever for the reply!

So is the idea as soon as I build a DataSource and JdbcTemplate to immediately call this method and mark the Connection as read only so all subsequent queries / inserts / updates / executes are read only?

Comment: unfortunately no, you have to run your JDBC with the connection using straight JDBC within the callback.